# Display contents of PHP code in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a script written in the crop.php file. I'm using it to perform some image processing. What I want is to get the code from this file and post it on the website, so that everyone will be able to see it.

Comment: Noone seems to be able to give you the correct answer. So here it is. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php , check the first comment and also notice extra solution in the doc "AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps". Now lets see how many change their answer.

Comment: It worked, if you post it as an Answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @user2840278 There are two ways of doing this, that I know of. [Consult my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19613924/1415724)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `highlight_file($file);`

[Read about it in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php)

Please notice the comments, they are riddled with suggestions for parsing with line numbers and etc.

And for a second solution the docs also state the following.

*"Many servers are configured to automatically highlight files with a phps extension. For example, example.phps when viewed will show the syntax highlighted source of the file. To enable this, add this line to the httpd.conf:
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps"*

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

If you just remove the `<?php` at the top that should do it, although it won't be well formatted but if users look at the source it should look like what you see.

If you want to make it look good I assume there are tools for that.

Comment: I made an edit your answer because you needed to mark `<?php` as code with backticks.  Without doing that, half of the text was hidden by the browser from the open tag.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. Alternatively, you can write another php script which would read (through fopen() function) from file.php and post it as text.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_show_source.asp

Make a new file called 'source.php' and include

show_source("crop.php");

or 2. 
Copy the contents of the file into a new file called 'code.html'. PHP by default only processes .php files.

Comment: Please do not link w3schools

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is copy the PHP code into a HTML document. Wrap in paragraph tags, like this: `<P> ... php code ... </P>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

// code to be shown start
phpinfo();
echo "This echo statement isn't executed";


/* Provoke an error -- bogus SQL syntax */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('bogus sql');
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
// code to be shown end

<?php 
$code = ob_get_clean();
highlight_string($code);
?>
```

Which will echo in your web browser but will not execute:

```
// code to be shown start
phpinfo();
echo "This echo statement isn't executed";


/* Provoke an error -- bogus SQL syntax */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('bogus sql');
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
// code to be shown end
```

However, do not include `<?php` or `?>` between `// code to be shown start` and `// code to be shown end` otherwise it will execute.

---

### Another way of doing this is: (will highlight code at the same time)

```
<?php
highlight_file("your_file_to_be_displayed.php");
?>
```

Using PHP's [`highlight_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) function

Comment: I never heard of the `highlight_file()` mate ! . +1 (Inclusive of detailed answer). Wish i could give +10.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It's a great function indeed, however it will highlight code, which may not always be what people want to do, which is why I put two different methods. Thanks Shankar :)